# What is a good open source pastebin in Python or Perl?

Tags: python, perl, open-source, pastebin

I'm looking for an open-source pastebin web-application written in either Python or Perl. 
I need it in order to implement a web-based specialized editor for my own needs, and I want to borrow code / ideas from the pastebin since I don't have much experience in web programming.

Can you point to one (or a few) ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Lodgeit](http://dev.pocoo.org/projects/lodgeit/) is written in Python and is a nice pastebin

Comment: Ah, great. I was aware of Lodgeit but didn't know how to get its code. 10x

Comment: Yeh, LodgdIt is great. I was actually going to post this, but I couldn't find the link. Thanks for this!

Comment: LodgeIt seems dead, such a shame :(

Comment: LodgeIt is not longer maintained http://paste.pocoo.org/about/ and is breaking with new versions of python-werkzeug... so probably not a great recommendation (unless a maintained fork emerges).

Answer (score 12):

I like [pastebot](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pastebot/), which powers http://paste.pocoo.org/ (for example). It's Perl and uses POE.

Comment: your link to sial.org doesn't work anymore

Comment: @fudgey I replaced it. I hope it will be reviewed and displayed soon.

Answer (score 3):

[Stickum](http://code.google.com/p/stickum/) is written using TurboGears and supports syntax highlighting for a large number of languages thanks to its use of [Pygments](http://pygments.org/). You can see it in action at the [Fedora Pastebin](http://fpaste.org/).

Answer (score 3):

http://dpaste.com/ is written in Python with Django.  From http://dpaste.com/about/:

> This site began as an exercise. It seemed silly that Django coders didn't have a pastebin app written in Django, when writing a pastebin app is just a couple steps above "Hello, World" in complexity. Initially it was all [generic views](http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/generic_views/) — in other words, it was some configuration info plus a couple templates — and worked great, but as I've added features some actual programming has been needed. The source to the "pure generic" version of the site is still available [here](http://dpaste.com/static/pastebin.tgz). At some point I may release the latest source, but that's contingent on finding time to do the cleanup and enhancements on my list.

The book [Python Web Development with Django](http://withdjango.com/) (co-written by [Paul Bissex](http://e-scribe.com/), the creator of dpaste) contains a chapter on creating a pastebin.

Comment: Adding a correction to this this nice old answer -- the core dpaste.com engine is no longer open source. However, on http://dpaste.com/opensource I do link to the original source referenced in this answer, and to a similar open source pastebin app I included in the Django book I co-wrote.

Answer (score 1):

Pastebot may be one of the original pastebins and is distributed on [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Bot-Pastebot/) and developed in github and/or gitorious these days.

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered Gist from the github?

http://gist.github.com/

> Gist is a simple way to share snippets and pastes with others. All gists are git repositories, so they are automatically versioned, forkable and usable as a git repository.

Comment: They are wanting a open source pastebin

Answer (score -2):

Hpaste is good. comes with pln txt and python highlighting (pygments) but u can add more easily. n if u need help u can contact the author (patx@patx.me). [hpaste wiki](http://bitbucket.org/patx/hpaste). also runs in pure python is veyr light wieght and easy to setup (upload to ur site).

Answer (score -2):

[Codepad.org](http://codepad.org/) is great for smallish examples, because it will compile and run your code.  This is invaluable for making sure you and whomever else are on the same page.  It is not open-source completely, but some [pieces it uses](http://www.xs4all.nl/~weegen/eelis/geordi/) are, and it's a good feature to consider.

Comment: Link to open-source "pieces" is 404.

Answer (score -3):

http://pastebin.im has the capability to debug over 50 programming languages.

It is running on pastebin.com's open-source application.

Comment: Dead link. Also I don't think there is such a thing as "pastebin.com's open-source application"; if there is, a link to it is needed.

Answer (score -3):

I've had a pretty good experience with the open-source PHP Stikked: http://code.google.com/p/stikked

Its written in CodeIgniter and installation is relatively painless.

Comment: neither python nor perl.